# Filter using  -replace

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

I'm trying to get my head around `-replace`. Can anybody help me?

As an exercise, I'm trying to simply filter:

```
@{processName=chrome}
```

So that `chrome` is returned to the listbox I'm trying to output it to.

So far I have:

```
$processnames = Get-Process | select ProcessName | -replace '^@{processname=',''
```

I know I'm doing something wrong, can somebody point me in the right direction and explain why please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to have the process name without the final `}`:

```
$Processnames = Get-Process | Select ProcessName | foreach { $_ -replace '^@{processname=(.*)}' , '$1' }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get process names without using replace operations:

```
Get-Process | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

To get just the chrome process:

```
Get-Process chrome | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

Answer (score 1):

Using -replace requires you have a object passed to it. So in order for your command to work:

```
$Processnames = Get-Process | Select ProcessName | 
   foreach {$_ -replace '^@{processname=',''}
```

Remember when you passing multiple objects down the pipe to manipulate you have to pass them into a `foreach` loop. You are telling it I want to take `$_` value and look for `^@processname=` and replace it with `blank`